# Printing pattern using for loop

Tags: python

Hello I need to print a pattern using # and - by writing an iterative code
Eg printpattern(3) should give output #-#—-#—--
Not sure how to add a # in front each time
Tried using a for loop and ended up with #-#--#--

heres what i got:

```py
def printpattern(number):
    count="-"
    x="#-"
    for i in range(1,number):
        count=x+count*i
    return count
```

Comment: Show us your for loop, and we might be able to help :) It looks like you're close, you just need to repeat how many dashes you do on each iteration of your main loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following should work...

```py
n = int(input("Enter n : "))

for i in range(n):
   res = "#-"

   for j in range(i):
      res += "-"

   print(res, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the '#' before adding the '-' symbol 'n' number of times. The sample code would look something like this:

```
inp = int(input("Enter size: "))
a='#'
b='-'
pat=''

for i in range(1,inp+1):
   pat = pat+a
   pat = pat+(b*i)

print(pat)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def printpattern(number):
    count = ''
    
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        count += '#' + ('-' * i)

    return count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(printpattern(3))
```